# plexus-compiler-eclipse error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to byte[]

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using plexus-compiler-eclipse-1.8.2 to compile my project using the eclipse compiler from maven. I'm using clone() to create a copy of an array:

```
byte[] copy = orig.clone();
```

and I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to byte[]
```

The same code compiles without this error with javac. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We must not rely on error/warning other than the ones given by the javac compile command. That includes both IDE warnings and command-line build tools like ant or maven. Sure its very user friendly to use them and not javac directly but when in doubt or contradictory results javac always has the final word. For example, using JDK1.6.0_29 on Eclipse Helios didn't raised any warning/nor error.